# Compare columns that don't contain specific string in one table

Tags: mysql, database

I have four columns in two tables, say C1,C2,C3 and C4. Now each of them can have any string value. I want to compare all the columns that are not having value "NOT POSSIBLE" value from Table 1. Say if C1 and C2 are having value "NOT POSSIBLE" then I will compare C3 and C4 from both tables.

It was easy case statement if we had two columns. But how to do with four columns ? Any good idea ?

For two columns, simple case like this will work :

```
CASE
        WHEN t1.C1 = 'NOT POSSIBLE' AND t1.C2 != 'NOT POSSIBLE'
        THEN t1.C2=t2.C2
        WHEN t1.C2 = 'NOT POSSIBLE' AND t1.C1 != 'NOT POSSIBLE'
        THEN t1.C1=t2.C1
        ELSE 
            t1.C1=t2.C1 AND 
            t1.C2=t2.C2
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (not regarding `null`-values)

```
(t1.C1 = 'NOT POSSIBLE' or t1.C1 = t2.C1) and (t1.C2 = 'NOT POSSIBLE' or t1.C2 = t2.C2) 
and (t1.C3 = 'NOT POSSIBLE' or t1.C3 = t2.C3) and (t1.C4 = 'NOT POSSIBLE' or t1.C4 = t2.C4)
```

Comment: What if all values are 'NOT POSSIBLE' ?

Comment: This will give far more results than required.

Comment: The question is: what SHOULD happen when all values are `not possible`? You didn't specify that. You just said:  "I want to compare all the columns that are not having value "NOT POSSIBLE" value from Table 1." and it does just that. But I (or you) can just add other stuff, if you tell me what other conditions are required, e.g. you can add `and not (t1.C1 = 'NOT POSSIBLE' and t1.C2 = 'NOT POSSIBLE' and t1.C3 = 'NOT POSSIBLE' and t1.C4 = 'NOT POSSIBLE')` to prevent 4 `not possible`-values.